exiftool-vendored: `extractBinaryTagToBuffer` Fails Unexpectedly
I want to read XMP data from PDFs in JavaScript:
const { exiftool } = require('exiftool-vendored');
const fs = require('fs');

async function extractXMPData(filename) {
    try {
        const buffer = await exiftool.extractBinaryTagToBuffer('XMP', filename);
        console.log(buffer.toString());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading XMP data:', error);
    }

    // Close the exiftool instance to free resources
    await exiftool.end();
}

const filename = process.argv[2];
extractXMPData(filename);

That fails with "Error reading XMP data: Error: XMP not found".
If I extract the XMP data on the command-line with exiftool -b -XMP /path/to/file.pdf, the XMP data is extracted.  Also when I write the data to a file with JavaScript:
await exiftool.extractBinaryTag('XMP', filename, 'out.xpacket');

Is this a bug in exiftool-vendored or am I doing something wrong?
